# jQuery.getJSON and jQuery.parseJSON return [object Object]?

Tags: json, jquery

**EDIT**: I've gotten the "famous question" badge with this question, so I figured I'd come back to it and stick what happened to me right at the very tippy top for people searching it to get an answer right away.

Basically, I was new to JSON. JSON is an object (obviously), as it contains all kinds of stuff! So I was like "Hey, javascript, just pop up an alert with all of this JSON data", expecting it to give me the JSON data as a string. But javascript doesn't do that (which is good!), so it was like "Hey, this is how we display objects, [object Object]".

What I could've done is something like `alert(obj.DATA[0][1])` and it would've shown me that bit of the object.

What I really wanted was to verify that I was making good JSON data, which I could've checked with `JSON.stringify`.

Anyway, back to our regularly scheduled questions!

---

I'm trying to get some JSON data with an ajax call, but jQuery doesn't seem to like my JSON.

if I do something like:

```
function init2() {
    alert("inside init2");
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/Mobile_ReportingChain.cfm",
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            alert(obj);
        }
    });
}
```

I get this as from alert(data):

```
    {"COLUMNS":["MFIRST_NAME","MLAST_NAME","MMDDL_NAME","MEMPLY_ID","MAIM_NBR","EMPLY_ID"],
    "DATA":[

["FNAME1          ","LNAME1                  ","MI1              ","000-14-7189","026-0010","000-62-7276"]      

,["FNAME2           ","LNAME2                    ","MI2              ","000-01-2302","101-1850","000-14-7189"]  

,["FNAME3           ","LNAME3                  ","MI3              ","000-91-3619","102-1000","000-01-2302"]    

,["FNAME4         ","LNAME4                  ","MI4              ","000-25-9687","102-1000","000-91-3619"]  

]}
```

which JSONLint says is valid json. alert(obj) gives me this, however:

```
[object Object]
```

adding `dataType: "json"` or `"text json"` just makes it report `[object Object]` at `alert(data)`.

I'd really like to get this figured out, does anyone know why it's doing this? I'm pretty new at jQuery, my goal is to get an array for each of the columns. The same code I'm using has worked on a different page it looks like, which is what's bothering me the most.

Comment: You are converting it to an object and then calling alert with that object. It then says hey this is an object. Everything is working as it should :)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The [`alert()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.alert) function can only display a string of text. As its only parameter it takes a string or an object. *The object will however be converted into a string that can be displayed.*

When fetching JSON through jQuery, the `$.ajax()` method will automatically parse the JSON and turn it into a JavaScript object for you. Your `data` variable is therefor a JavaScript object, and not a JSON string as one might expect.

Since `alert()` only can display strings, when trying to alert your `data` object, your object will be turned into its string representation. The string representation of a JavaScript object is `[object Object]`.

For debug-purposes you can use `console.log(data)` instead. You can then inspect the object and its content through the console in your browsers developer tools.

```
function init2() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/Mobile_ReportingChain.cfm",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

*If you for some reason still want to alert the JSON-data, then you would have to turn your `data` object back into a JSON-string. To do that you can make use of [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):*

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: That was quick, and I feel silly. Thanks everyone, you were the fastest and gave me the info the console.log(data), so you win the answer!

Comment: @Nopzen Glad it was helpful to you!

Answer (score 11):

it wants a string

```
 var obj = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Answer (score 4):

try sending that object to `console.log`. You'll get a clearer picture what does it contain.

Also, put `dataType: 'json'` and remove `parseJSON` because it's all the same.

Comment: Yeah, once I knew that I was getting the JSON properly, I replaced it with $.getJSON.

Answer (score 2):

This is how it's supposed to work.  Your JSON becomes a javascript object.  You can then manipulate that object as a regular javascript object.

`data.COLUMNS` for instance should return an array.

Answer (score 2):

`[object Object]` is the string representation of a javascript object.

Try accessing properties of the object.

```
alert(data.COLUMNS[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

`jQuery.parseJSON` will convert the json string into json object so alert(obj) will show you `[object Object]` since it is an object.

If you want to see what  `obj` contains then use `console.log(obj)` and then check console log message.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$.getJSON( "UI/entidades.json.php", function(data){
 result = JSON.stringify(data);
 alert(result)
 console.log(result)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

(I knows this is an jquery problem; but just bear with me for a min. so that i can explain why this problem occurred to me in the first place).
I wanted to fill in the gaps made my deletion of records in my MySQL table ( primary key that was auto increment. So when records where deleted in between my id had missing keys. I though some mechanism to show those missing keys. So i created the code that created an array through a loop then deleted those keys that were present and echo backed that array (of course json_encode that array).
But to my amazement what ever I did it always end up giving me [object Object].
It baffled me a lot that were was the problem.

---

Solution: Just realigning the array and all my problem gone.

Below I would give an simplified example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="../js/jquery/jquery3.x/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
        $('#generate').click(function () {
          $.get('tmp2.php?tab=1', function (data) {
            var retStr = '<table>';
            var par = $.parseJSON(data);
            $(par).each(function () {
              retStr += '<tr><td>' + this + '</td></tr>';
            });
            retStr += '</table>';
            $('#res').html(retStr);
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
        <input type="button" value="generate" id="generate" />
        <div id="res"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the controller

```
<?php
if (!empty($_GET['tab'])) {
  $ids = array();
  for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++)
    $ids[] = $i;
  for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i = $i + 2)
    unset($ids[$i]);
  // echo json_encode($ids); // this will generate [object Object]
  $res = array();
  foreach ($ids as $key => $value) {
    $res[] = $value;
  }
  echo json_encode($res);
  exit();
}
?>
```