# Using AJAX to Dynamically Fill a Dropdown VB.Net JQuery

Tags: vb.net, jquery

I am trying to make an AJAX call to fill a dropdown when a value is selected in another dropdown. Currently, I am getting a SyntaxError: Invalid Character error, but if I remove the "dataType: json", I get this mess that looks like HTML code. The dropdown must be bound using value and text pairs. This is my ASPX code related to the dropdown:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"      CodeBehind="Request.aspx.vb" Inherits="NDBEDP.Request" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.entityDrop').live('change', function (event) {
            loadStateDrop()
        });

        var loadStateDrop = function () {
            var data = "{'entity':'"+ $('#<%=ddlEntity.ClientID%> option:selected').val()+"'}"
            alert("before ajax(), val: " + $('#<%=ddlEntity.ClientID%> option:selected').val());
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Request.aspx/loadStates",
                datatype: "JSON",
                data: data,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (list) {
                    alert(list);
                    $('.stateDrop').empty()
                    $.each(list, function (element) {
                        var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
                        optn.text = element.StateAbbr;
                        optn.value = element.StateID;
                        $('.stateDrop').append(optn);
                    });
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("Error updating dropdowns: " + errorThrown);
                }
            });
        };
    </script>
    <asp:panel ID="userInput" runat="server">
        <asp:panel id="userInformation" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" style="margin-bottom: 0px">
            <asp:DropdownList cssClass="entryField, entityDrop" ID="ddlEntity" runat="server" Width="95%"></asp:DropdownList>
            <asp:DropDownList cssClass="entryField, stateDrop" ID="ddlExpenseState" runat="server" Width="18%"></asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlExpensePeriod" runat="server" cssClass="entryField" Width="50%"></asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlExpenseYear" runat="server" cssClass="entryField" Width="20%"></asp:DropDownList>
        </asp:panel>
    </asp:panel>
</asp:Content>
```

This is my VB.Net code:

```
Imports NDBEDP.StringExtensions
Imports NDBEDP.DropdownExtensions
Imports NDBEDP.GridViewExtensions
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Script.Services
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization

Public Class Request
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function loadStates(entity As Integer) As Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
        Dim expenseStates As DataSet = (New RequestBus).getExpenseStates(entity)
        Dim returnStates As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
        For i As Integer = 0 To expenseStates.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            returnStates.Add(expenseStates.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("StateAbbr"), expenseStates.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("StateID"))
        Next
        Return returnStates
    End Function
End Class
```

Let me know if you need to see any other code to help.

I have tried doing this through WebServices, but couldn't get that to work either. As soon as I included a WebService and hooked it up properly, before adding any of my own code, I got: JavaScript critical error at line 3, column 1 web service script1002 syntax error. I would prefer to do this in a WebService, but I'm open to anything that I can get to work.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Edit: Changed to match current code

Answer (score 0):

First off, you do not need to serialize the data coming back from your ASP.NET AJAX Page Method, as it JSON serializes the data by default.

Second, why are you not returning a type from you method? It is a `Function` and there is no return type declared. It appears you want to return a `List(Of T)` so that you can loop through the results client-side.

Here is an example page method that returns the current time as a `String`:

```
<WebMethod> _
Public Shared Function GetDate() As String
    Return DateTime.Now.ToString()
End Function
```

Please read this to become more familiar with [Using jQuery to directly call ASP.NET AJAX page methods](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

Comment: I couldn't get it to work with a return type either. I tried returning a Dictionary(Of String, Integer) and, with or without the dataType in the AJAX call, I'm still getting the HTML mess.

Comment: You are not sending any `data` via the `.ajax()` call to the page method.

Comment: Updated answer with blog entry for how to use jQuery `.ajax()` and ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods together.

Comment: I guess I deleted that accidentally in all my changes. I added it back in, but it didn't change the result.

Comment: Update your question with the latest code you have for both AJAX code and page method code.

Comment: You need to send your data as `JSON` instead of just the value selected from the dropdown list as a single string value. You need something passed like this: {'entity':'7'}

Comment: I changed that, but I'm still getting the HTML. I updated the code above to reflect the change.

Comment: You have `entity`, but it needs to be `'entity'`. Are you familiar with `JSON`?

Comment: This is the second time I'm using it and the first time didn't require parameters (in or out). I fixed that problem, but I'm still getting the same result. I changed the code in the question to reflect the fix.

Comment: Make this `var data = {entity: $('#<%=ddlEntity.ClientID%> option:selected').val()}` be this `var data = {'entity': "'" + $('#<%=ddlEntity.ClientID%> option:selected').val() + "'"};`

Comment: I changed the code. I'm now reaching the server and getting a slightly better return value: [object Object].

Comment: Now your issue is that you are using the `index` value of the `.each()` as the `ID` value of your state returned. The `element` value is holding both pieces of state data, `element.StateAbbr` and `element.StateID`.

Comment: I've changed the code to match what I have now. I'm now getting 'undefined'. The Dictionary I'm returning has the correct values when I leave the function.

Comment: Is `element` undefined?

Comment: It seems to be, but I don't understand why. How do I get the information that is returned?

Comment: Change `$.each(list, function (element) {` to `$.each(list, function (key, value) {` and see if `key` or `value` or both are `undefined`.

Comment: It looked like the key was d and the value is [object Object]. I got it to work by using Firebug's `console.log(list)` (I got the idea from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9218900/jquery-getjson-and-jquery-parsejson-return-object-object)) and exploring the returned object. The data was just hidden because it was encapsulated in an object and I had to add `.d` to `list` in the `each()` line. I will copy my final code into the answer. Thank you very much Karl.

Comment: Ah yes the lovely `.d` problem, check out [Never worry about ASP.NET AJAX’s .d again](http://encosia.com/never-worry-about-asp-net-ajaxs-d-again/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the final jQuery code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"      CodeBehind="Request.aspx.vb" Inherits="NDBEDP.Request" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.entityDrop').live('change', function (event) {
            loadStateDrop()
        });

        var loadStateDrop = function () {
            var data = "{'entity':'"+ $('#<%=ddlEntity.ClientID%> option:selected').val()+"'}"
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Request.aspx/loadStates",
                datatype: "JSON",
                data: data,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (list) {
                    $('.stateDrop').empty();
                    if (list.hasOwnProperty("d")) {
                         $.each(list.d, function (key, value) {
                             var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
                             optn.text = key;
                             optn.value = value;
                             $('.stateDrop').append(optn);
                         });
                     }
                     else {
                         $.each(list, function (key, value) {
                             var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
                             optn.text = key;
                             optn.value = value;
                             $('.stateDrop').append(optn);
                         });
                     }
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("Error updating dropdowns: " + errorThrown);
                }
            });
        };
    </script>
    <asp:panel ID="userInput" runat="server">
        <asp:panel id="userInformation" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" style="margin-bottom: 0px">
            <asp:DropdownList cssClass="entryField, entityDrop" ID="ddlEntity" runat="server" Width="95%"></asp:DropdownList>
            <asp:DropDownList cssClass="entryField, stateDrop" ID="ddlExpenseState" runat="server" Width="18%"></asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlExpensePeriod" runat="server" cssClass="entryField" Width="50%"></asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlExpenseYear" runat="server" cssClass="entryField" Width="20%"></asp:DropDownList>
        </asp:panel>
    </asp:panel>
</asp:Content>
```

This is my VB.Net code (I probably don't need all of the includes):

```
Imports NDBEDP.StringExtensions
Imports NDBEDP.DropdownExtensions
Imports NDBEDP.GridViewExtensions
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Script.Services
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization

Public Class Request
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function loadStates(entity As Integer) As Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
        Dim expenseStates As DataSet = (New RequestBus).getExpenseStates(entity)
        Dim returnStates As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
        For i As Integer = 0 To expenseStates.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            returnStates.Add(expenseStates.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("StateAbbr"), expenseStates.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("StateID"))
        Next
        Return returnStates
    End Function
End Class
```

**Edited** to take advantage of [this article](http://encosia.com/never-worry-about-asp-net-ajaxs-d-again)