# Get Flickr image parameters from json format into variables

Tags: jquery, callback, undefined, getjson, flickr

I'm a little confused right now. I've looked at jQuery documentation, Flickr documentation, and a bunch of similar examples online, but it's not clear to me what I'm missing here.

Basically, I want to return the parameters for a single photo and put specific ones into variables. In my test, I started with an alert to make sure it was returning the data, but I can't get it to work.

```
$.getJSON('http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?&method=flickr.photos.getInfo&api_key=' + apiKey + '&photo_id=' + photoId + '&format=json&jsoncallback=?',
                function(data) {
                    alert(data.photo.id);
                });
```

and here's a sample of data that is returned from the url above

```
jsonFlickrApi({
"photo":{
  "id":"9691687487",
  "secret":"38a52fd5ae",
  "server":"3700",
  "farm":4,
  "dateuploaded":"1378570461",
  "isfavorite":0,
  "license":"4",
  "safety_level":"0",
  "rotation":0,
  "originalsecret":"a2fb99d8e4",
  "originalformat":"jpg",
  "owner":{
     "nsid":"41141575@N03",
     "username":"helmuthess",
     "realname":"",
     "location":"",
     "iconserver":"5457",
     "iconfarm":6,
     "path_alias":"helmuthess"
  },
  "title":{
     "_content":"Splash"
  }...
```

I get an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

And I've tried redefining what I'm trying to access, thinking I just don't understand the correct way, but I always get that something is undefined.

Also, when I just do `alert(data);` it shows `[object Object]`

Any clarification on what I'm not understanding would be much appreciated.

Comment: this answer may be relevant, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9218900/jquery-getjson-and-jquery-parsejson-return-object-object

Comment: Which version of jQuery is used? It's JSONP used here, and the result is actually a script with callback function wrapping the data structure, but that's ok, jQuery knows how to deal with it. Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jMZtu/); what's different in your code?

Comment: @sdeburca That actually explained my problem. I was trying to alert an object, but you can only alert strings. So knowing that, I was able to see that the data was in fact there. I just need to convert the objects I need into strings, so that I can use them the way I need to. Thanks!